# How to use chrome profile in puppeteer

Tags: automated-tests, puppeteer

I am unable to use specific profile in Puppeteer. It always open the chrome as a new user.

For example: I have 3 profiles for my chrome. Following is the code I am using to open chrome in specific profile:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
    // args: ['--profile-directory="Profile 1"'],
    userDataDir:"C:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1"
  });
```

But it always open the chrome as "Current user" profile.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try below code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false, args:[
'--user-data-dir=/user/data/directory/profile_n']
});
```

Full explanation is given here:

[In Puppeteer how to switch to chrome window from default profile to desired profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623828/in-puppeteer-how-to-switch-to-chrome-window-from-default-profile-to-desired-prof/57662769#57662769)

Comment: @nbi If this has solved your problem, then requesting you to kindly consider is as an Answer to your question.

Comment: This answer works great to persist a profile across runs and doesn't require any UI operations

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays this should work with:

```
args: ['--profile-directory="Profile 1"'],
userDataDir:"C:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"
```