# In Puppeteer how to switch to chrome window from default profile to desired profile

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, chromium, puppeteer, browser-automation

My requirement is to test chrome extensions on a new profile.

I referred https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ for Chromium args[--user-data-dir, --profile-directory]

After the browser is launched, 2 chrome windows are opened. One with given profile and extension and another with default profile and given extension. Also the focus is on a window with default profile. So all actions are happening on it.

I had expected that only 1 browser window would be opened with desired profile and extension.

I tried to switch focus to desired window but browser.BrowserContexts().length is 1, which is browser with default profile. Also browser.targets() shows that there is only 1 target with type as browser.

My Environment:

1. Puppeteer version: 6.9.0

2. Platform / OS version: Windows 10 Pro version 1803

3. URLs (if applicable):

4. Node.js version: 10.16.3

What I tried:

a. Open chrome.exe from path\to\my\project\node_modules\puppeteer.local-chromium\win64-674921\chrome-win\chrome.exe

b. Click on profile icon and open Manage People dialog.

c. Add new person (Profile)

d. Open chrome://version and make a note of Profile Path and close the browser.

e. Create example1.js, example2.js and execute it using node example1.js, node example2.js. The code for both examples are given below.

example1.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false, args:['--disable-extensions-except=\\path\\to\\my\\extension',
'--load-extension=\\path\\to\\my\\extension',
'--user-data-dir=%userprofile%\\AppData\\Local\\Chromium\\User Data',
'--profile-directory=Profile 1'
]});

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.waitFor(5000);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

example2.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false, args:['--disable-extensions-except=c:\\dev\\prj\\vpnteam\\global VPN\\extension', 
                                                                '--load-extension=c:\\dev\\prj\\vpnteam\\global VPN\\extension',
                                                                '--user-data-dir=c:\\Users\\govinda.s\\AppData\\Local\\Chromium\\User Data',
                                                                '--profile-directory=Profile 1'
                                                            ]});
  console.log(browser.browserContexts().length);
  var x = await browser.targets();
  for(let i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
    if(x[i].type()==='browser')
    {
        console.log(x[i]['_targetInfo']['targetId']);
    }
  }
  await browser.close();
})();
```

I had expected Puppeteer should launch Chrome with given:

a. Profile

b. Given extension should be loaded for that profile.

However, apart from above expectations,

a. A browser with default profile is also launched. In total 2 browser windows are opened.

b. The browser with default profile also has given extension loaded.

c. By default, the browser with default profile has focus.

d. browser.browserContexts().length is 1

e. There is only 1 target with type browser

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, I found the reason.

But first i would like to add that the issue is not in puppeteer. The issue is how chromium flag `--user-data-dir` works and the way i expected it to work.

My understanding was that arg `--user-data-dir` is specified to change default dir for user data. The default dir where chromium searches for user data is `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data` but when arg `--user-data-dir` is used then it appends '\Default' to specific dir. So it becomes `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Default` instead, which is a profile directory.

Hence there was no need of arg `--profile-directory`. But since I had used it, I also instructed chromium to consider using specific profile.

There is definitely some clash of args here which led to opening of 2 browsers. One with specified profile and another with default.

So what I did instead is:

1. I moved contents of directory `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Profile 1` to `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Profile 1\Default`. I created 'Default' Directory inside Profile 1 directory.
2. Removed arg `--profile-directory` and set `--user-data-dir=%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Profile 1`.

Now, what chromium does is, it changes it to `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Profile 1\Default`. This way I can use puppeteer to launch using desired profile.

Final Code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false, args:['--disable-extensions-except=/path/to/my/extension',
                                                                '--load-extension=/path/to/my/extension',
                                                                '--user-data-dir=%userprofile%\\AppData\\Local\\Chromium\\User Data\\Profile 1'
                                                                //'--profile-directory=Profile 1'
                                                            ]});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("http://www.google.com");
  await page.waitFor(5000)
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Now I have 1 unanswered question left. What is the intended use of arg `--profile-directory`?

Comment: Niche analysis. were you able to load the existing browser config then? I'm trying nothing helps yet :/

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean by existing browser config? Can you describe what u were trying to achieve and what u have tried till now? However, if you meant that was i able to launch a browser with new profile and load desired extension only then Yes, I was successful in achieving it using above mentioned soln.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed in the meantime, meaning you can use --user-data-dir and --profile-directory together now in up to date browsers (including Chrome, Edge, etc).

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work. Turns out the code I inherited included default args were sent to puppeteer. These default args already a default user-data-dir in that points to the temp folder, which came first so Chrome was using the temp dir even though I was specifying something different. I couldn't change the defaults around so the fix I found was to use userDataDir direct with  puppeteer.launch, which takes precedence over the args. Using chrome://version was very useful debugging which profile directory is being used.

Answer (score 3):

We need to use puppeteer-core in order to utilize the exsting chrome/edge etc. I found the following working in my windows10.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
        args: [
            '--user-data-dir=%userprofile%\\AppData\\Local\\Chrome\\User Data',
            '--profile-directory=Profile 8'
        ]
    });
})();
```