# How to use existing Firefox profile in Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, firefox, puppeteer, firefox-profile

I need to use an existing Firefox profile in Puppeteer using NodeJS. That profile has a history, configured add-ons, proxy-servers & cookies that I need.

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried to copy the profile in to `node_modules/pupeteer/...`, analog to your local configuration?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. But I'd like to do this with puppeteer.

Comment: Marc, Firefox Nightly default profile is not used when starting puppeteer.

Comment: Try it wit CLI args: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57614183/5781499 & https://support.mozilla.org/bg/questions/1257582?&mobile=0

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried with full PATH to Firefox Nightly profile folder and with profile name, as in Firefox Profile Manager.

Comment: Then i have no other clue :/

Comment: Marc, thanks a lot. Do any of these tips work for you?

Comment: I havnt tried nor i have the need to use a existing profile. That are just things that came in my mind while i read your question :)